# How Do I Add a View to An Ember Template So That Its Controller Is Injected

Tags: templates, dependency-injection, controller, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am adding a view to a template using the following:

```
{{view NewsCMS.NewsItemView itemBinding="news_item" class="news-item" }}
```

**It seems that Ember does not inject its controller automatically, so how should I inject a controller into this view?**

I have a controller set up:

```
NewsCMS.NewsItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  someAction: function() {
    console.log("CLICKED");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the {{render}} helper instead of the {{view}} helper to automatically set up the controller context: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/render.js